# Understanding the TimeSeriesDataSet in pytorch forecasting

Tags: python, pytorch, forecasting, pytorch-dataloader

Here is a code sample taken from one of pytorch forecasting tutorila:

```
# create dataset and dataloaders
max_encoder_length = 60
max_prediction_length = 20

training_cutoff = data["time_idx"].max() - max_prediction_length

context_length = max_encoder_length
prediction_length = max_prediction_length

training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    data[lambda x: x.time_idx <= training_cutoff],
    time_idx="time_idx",
    target="value",
    categorical_encoders={"series": NaNLabelEncoder().fit(data.series)},
    group_ids=["series"],
    # only unknown variable is "value" - and N-Beats can also not take any additional variables
    time_varying_unknown_reals=["value"],
    max_encoder_length=context_length,
    max_prediction_length=prediction_length,
)

validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, data, min_prediction_idx=training_cutoff + 1)
batch_size = 128
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
```

I don't really understand how the validation dataset is done with respect to the time index. I also don't understand why there is no test dataset in the tutorial. is it for a specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning validation dataset:

training dataset is all data except the last `max_prediction_length` data points of each Time series (each time series correspond to datapoints with same `group_ids`).
Those last datapoints are filtered by the training cutoff (cutoff is the same for each time series because they are of same size)

validation data is the last `max_prediction_length` data points use as targets for each time series (which mean validation data are the last `encoder_length + max_prediction_length` of each time series).
This is done by using parameter `min_prediction_idx=training_cutoff + 1` which make the dataset taking only data with `time_index` with value superior to `training_cutoff + 1` (minimal decoder index is always >= min_prediction_idx)

Comment: very much appreciated. clear explanation